# How to create multiple instances of an activity?

Tags: android

I want to create multiple instances of an activity in the same process. Should I use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag like the code below?

```
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(this, A.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
                startActivity(i);
```

This code is executed in class A to create another instance of activity A.

This question, will this code create another task? As I understand is a process can only have one task. Does it mean the two activities will exist in different tasks? That's what I want. I want the two activities to be in the same process.

Thanks.

Comment: Just curious, why are you trying to create multiple activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start the activity, with no special flags. Activities create multiple instances by default. In fact, you have to do some work to *prevent* getting multiple instances when you don't want them.